# If checkbox checked then trick button to continue to next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I do this is Javascript? I'm trying to figure out a way in Javascript to trigger that submit button below if checkbox is checked. Which is it.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product[6]" value="1" checked="checked">

<input type="submit" value="Continue">
```

Thank for you any help!

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

You can handle `submit()` event and add condition like bellow :

**JS :**

```
$("#target").submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent submit action here

    //Condition on checkbox
    if($( "input[name='product[6]']:checked" )){
        $('#submit-btn').click(); //handle submit if condition true
    }
});
```

Comment: might be other checkboxes on the page

Comment: @charlietfl - true! but there is only for this example i'm using!

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity and specificity of which checkbox am adding ID's to elements

```
<input id="product6" type="checkbox" name="product[6]" value="1" checked="checked">    
<input id="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Continue">
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){

    if( $('#product6').is(':checked') ){
        $('#submit-btn').click();
        // or submit the form
        $('#product6').closest('form').submit();
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you! I literary just did the same thing! haha Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

First you want to give the checkbox input an id (checkbox-id for example)
and for the submit input (submit-id for example)

```
document.getElementById("checkbox-id").onclick = myFunction;

function myFunction()
{
    document.getElementById("submit-id").click();
    //Or
    document.getElementById("submit-id").submit();
}
```